# Как из cписка организованного как очереди сделать кольцевой?

Tags: c, список, очередь

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LMES 100


typedef struct inform { 
    int index;
    char message[LMES];
} INFORM;
typedef struct list_elem { 
    INFORM inform;
    struct list_elem* next;
} LEL;
void MakeList(void); 
LEL* AddElem(LEL* last);
void PrintList(void);
void FreeList(void);
LEL* list; 
void main(){
    MakeList(); 
    PrintList(); 
    FreeList(); 
}

void MakeList(void)
{
    puts("\n Вхідні дані (для завершення індекс - 0):\n");
    LEL* end = NULL; 
    do 
        end = AddElem(end);
    while (end != NULL);
}

LEL* AddElem(LEL* last)
{
    LEL* pel; 
    static int num = 1; 
    pel = (LEL*)malloc(sizeof(LEL)); 
    if (pel == NULL)
    {
        puts("\n Немає більше вільної пам\'яті...\n Формування списку завершено.");
        free(pel);
        return NULL; 
    }
    printf("\n %d елемент: індекс - ", num);
    scanf_s("%d", &pel->inform.index);
    if (pel->inform.index == 0) { 
       free(pel);
        return NULL;
    }
    rewind(stdin); 
    printf("Повідомлення: ");
    gets_s(pel->inform.message);
    pel->next = NULL; 
    if (list == NULL) 
        list = pel; 
    else
        last->next = pel; 
    num++;
    return pel;
}
void PrintList(void)
{
    LEL* pel = list;
    puts("\n\n\t Сформований список:\n");
    while (pel != NULL) {
        printf("%10d\t%-70s\n", pel->inform.index, pel->inform.message);
        pel = pel->next;
    }
}

void FreeList(void)
{
    LEL* pel = list;
    while (pel != NULL) {
        list = list->next; 
        free(pel); 
        pel = list;
    }
}
```

Можно ли из cписка организованного как очереди сделать кольцевой?
Если можно то как?

Comment: Нет проблем. `LEL *end = MakeList(); if (end) end->next = list;`

Comment: А как мне присвоить  функцию MakeList() указателю end,он же в нутри этой функции ? И может объяснить почему так?

Comment: Так сделайте ее `LEL *MakeList()` (ну, немного переделайте возврат признака конца из `AddElem()`)  и возвращайте этот указатель

Comment: А можете объяснить почему так?

Comment: Не понял вопроса "почему так?". Почему список станет кольцевым если у его последнего элемента заменить нулевой указатель на начало списка?

Comment: @avp, ну-ну, не всё так просто. Надо где-то голову хранить, и все функции обязаны принимать голову списка в качестве параметра. Иначе будет "весело".

Comment: @0andriy, голова такого циклического списка, вообще-то говоря, вещь условная. Указатель на любой из элементов такого списка можно назначить головой. Другой вопрос, что разумных примеров использования циклических однонаправленных списков надо еще поискать. Другое дело, это циклический двунаправленный список с головой в нем же (голова ссылается на первый и последний элементы, а те в свою очередь на нее). Это одна из основных структур в ядре линукса

Comment: @avp, я в курсе про то, как это в Linux kernel сделано. Мне интереснее обсудить вариант этого вопроса, а именно про голову. Вы говорите "условная", всё же нет. У вас нарушается принцип FIFO/LIFO.

Comment: @0andriy, если вам нужно использовать в своей задаче LIFO/FIFO с циклическим списком, то просто храните и используйте указатель `end`. Доступ по нему -- последний элемент. Доступ по end->next -- первый. Можете добавлять в хвост (очередь) и при этом модифицировать end. Можете удалять голову, изменяя end->next. Для удаления хвоста придется просмотреть весь список. Особых достоинств у подобной организации списка вроде нет.  но как-то так я это вижу.